# How to implement the Drop or Trigger properly inside of Cypress?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, automated-tests, cypress, salesforce-lightning

I'm currently working with Salesforce with the "Drag File Here" component and it seems that if I work with the "Drag and Drop" NPM dependency it will do it without any errors but the screen will never pop up.

Note: After we drop a file, we should see a pop-up window with all the file options to store that file.

If I do it with the "Trigger Action" I will get the following error message:

[image]

My code is the following:

```
describe("Checklist - Drag and Drop Functionality", function () {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login();
  });

  it("Drag and Drop Files", () => {
    cy.viewOpportunityRecord();
    cy.wait(10000);
    // Click to view  More Tabs inside of the opportunity
    cy.get('button[title="More Tabs"]', { delay: 1000, force: true }).click({multiple: true, force: true});

    cy.get("span.slds-truncate")
      .contains("Checklist (beta)")
      .dblclick({ multiple: true });

    cy.wait(10000)

    const filePath = 'html-cheat-sheet.csv'
    
    cy.xpath('//*[@id="tab-18"]/slot/flexipage-component2/slot/flexipage-aura-wrapper/div/section[1]/h2/div[2]/button[3]').click({force: true})

    cy.wait(10000)
    cy.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/one-record-home-flexipage2/forcegenerated-adg-rollup_component___force-generated__flexipage_-record-page___-opportunity_-record_-page___-opportunity___-v-i-e-w/forcegenerated-flexipage_opportunity_record_page_opportunity__view_js/record_flexipage-record-page-decorator/div[1]/records-record-layout-event-broker/slot/slot/flexipage-record-home-with-subheader-template-desktop2/div/div[3]/div[1]/slot/slot/flexipage-component2[1]/slot/flexipage-tabset2/div/lightning-tabset/div/slot/slot/slot/flexipage-tab2[16]/slot/flexipage-component2/slot/flexipage-aura-wrapper/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]').trigger('drop', {filePath})

  })

})
```

Also, to run the drag the file, I thought that I can do this:

```
const fileLocated = cy.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/one-record-home-flexipage2/forcegenerated-adg-rollup_component___force-generated__flexipage_-record-page___-opportunity_-record_-page___-opportunity___-v-i-e-w/forcegenerated-flexipage_opportunity_record_page_opportunity__view_js/record_flexipage-record-page-decorator/div[1]/records-record-layout-event-broker/slot/slot/flexipage-record-home-with-subheader-template-desktop2/div/div[3]/div[1]/slot/slot/flexipage-component2[1]/slot/flexipage-tabset2/div/lightning-tabset/div/slot/slot/slot/flexipage-tab2[16]/slot/flexipage-component2/slot/flexipage-aura-wrapper/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]')
    
    cy.xpath('//*[@id="tab-18"]/slot/flexipage-component2/slot/flexipage-aura-wrapper/div/section[1]/h2/div[2]/button[3]').click({force: true})

    cy.wait(10000)
    cy.xpath('//*[@id="fileTable"]').xpath('//*[@id="fileTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/button').contains('12 Month Payment History').drag(fileLocated, { force: true})
```

The main issue with this is that I'm getting the following issue:

```
CypressError
Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.

The command that returned the promise was:

  > cy.wrap()
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To eliminate this issue, we were able to add a data attribute to the HTML page where the element is located. After that, I was able to get the xpath from that element and I was able to attach a file.

Example:

```
cy.xpath('//*[@id="cy-dropzone"]').attachFile('latestLead.json', {subjectType: 'drag-n-drop'})
```

Now, the issue has been resolved!

Comment: It looks like you also need to install the package `cypress-file-upload` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this solves it, but you can't do

```js
const fileLocated = cy.xpath(<horrendously-long-xpath-selector>)
...
cy.xpath(<another-long-xpath-selector>).drag(fileLocated, { force: true})
```

because `fileLocated` will not be an element (which is what you need as a drop target), it will be a Chainer.

Instead, do this

```js
cy.xpath(<horrendously-long-xpath-selector>)
  .then( targetItem => {

    ...
    cy.xpath(<another-long-xpath-selector>).drag( targetItem, { force: true})
  })
```